# Is there a way to take medications that come in capsules that may be gelatine?

Tags: ethics, medicine, gelatin

Reading another answer here I realised that medication capsules are likely made out of gelatine.

Is there an alternative way to take the medication?  Might this affect the medication?

I take very little medication at all, but now I am aware of this any time I might have to take some it will be in my mind.

Comment: I would suspect you'd have to look into specific alternatives for each medicine.

Comment: Have you also realized that most medication is tested on animals and that sometimes animal tests are even mandated by law to get the permission to sell the medication? Compared to this you don't need to worry about that bit of gelatine... and still I, in your case, would prefer to stay alive than to save those animals. ;-)

Comment: @nobody it might not have anything to do with staying alive.

Comment: @Steve Or getting better from an illness. If there is no pressing reason to take it, then I wouldn't call it medication, but maybe I understand the word the wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talk to your doctor/pharmacist.  The medicines are often available in alternate forms, but it will depend on the specific medication.  Your doctor may be able to prescribe a different form, or the pharmacist may be able to supply the medicine with a non-gelatin capsule.

Answer (score 3):

Non-gelatine empty capsules can easily be found online for purchase in standard sizes.

[image: empty capsule size example]

Filler racks and tampers (a tool for filling single or multiple capsules) are also readily available from popular online general retailers.

This would allow for the contents of gelatine capsules to be transferred to non-gelatine capsules.

Due to the nature of medicines it would be advisable to proceed with caution in doing this and seek the advice of a qualified pharmacist beforehand.

Comment: Will these work for liquids (e.g. oils) as well?