# Are there any anti seizure meds suitable for vegans?

Tags: is-it-vegan

I know that it's not a good idea to seek medical advice here, but I just want to ask about whether or not the option even exists. If you would recommend something particular, I would definitely consult with my physician before taking it. My seizures are not epileptic.

Many thanks!

Comment: why are the meds not suitable for vegans?

Comment: There's often gelatine and lactose there

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/696/is-there-a-way-to-take-medications-that-come-in-capsules-that-may-be-gelatine

Answer (score 4):

The Vegan Society UK provides [this statement](https://www.vegansociety.com/go-vegan/definition-veganism) about medicines:

> The Vegan Society DOES NOT recommend you avoid medication prescribed to you by your doctor. [...]
> What you can do is ask your GP or pharmacist to provide you, if possible, with medication that does not contain animal products such as gelatine or lactose.

Asking your pharmacist for gelatine-free capsules is your best option. Gelatine is not an active ingredient in most medications, so it's possible that alternatives may be available in your area.