# Is there a vegan cineol (eucalypus oil) capsule supplement?

Tags: health, substitutes, supplements, gelatin

Cineol is used to treat respiratory illnesses, and one typical way to take it is in a gelatine capsule. The reason for doing so is that the oil passes mouth and stomach in the capsule, it would not be possible to swallow this amount of cineol (typically 200 mg) otherwise.

But so far, I have not been able to find pure cineol capsules that contain a high dosage of cineol, without gelatine. The most I could find is some kind of mixed herb & vitamin supplement with 40 mg cineol added. This is not very much, and contains a lot of other ingredients.

*Are there vegan cineol capsules with a sufficiently high dosage?*

One possibility might be making them yourself: https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1895/47